# What does it mean to short a futures contract?

Tags: investing, foreign-exchange, futures

I am currently studying the convergence of futures price to spot prices.

I know that as the delivery month of a futures contract is approached, the futures price converges to the spot price of the underlying asset. When the delivery period is reached, the futures price equals—or is very close to—the spot price.

However why text book gives an example to explain this:

To see why this is so, we first suppose that the futures price is above the spot price during the delivery period. Traders then have a clear arbitrage opportunity:

1.Short a futures contract.

2.Buy the asset.

3.Make the delivery.

'These steps are certain to lead to a profit equal to the amount by which the futures price exceeds the spot price. As traders exploit this arbitrage opportunity, the futures price will fall.'

Why would he sell the future's contract? Does this have to do with futures prices being higher than short prices?

I don't get the 'short a future contract'. I know it means selling a future contract, but then it states to buy the asset . Which asset? What does selling a future contact have to do with buying an asset?

If you sell a futures contract, what asset would you be buying?

Why are these steps certain to lead to a profit equal to the amount by which the futures price exceeds the spot price?

I am new to finance so a simple explanation of what im not understanding would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you sell the futures contract, the contract basically says that, if you hold it to the contract date, you promise to sell whatever is being contracted for at the specified price.  If you buy the contract and hold to that date, then you promise to buy.  So being long or short on a future means exactly what the terms would suggest, that you are going to be long or short on the underlying in the future - whenever the date of the contract is for.

Now when it says "buy the asset", it means to buy whatever the underlying is *now*.  So suppose the contract was for oil, if you were contracting to sell oil in December, you would buy oil now.  That way when it comes time for you to sell oil as promised, you already have it ready to deliver. 
 (You are "short against the barrel" so to speak.) Then, all you have to do is pay storage costs for a short period of time until the contract date, and then you deliver the oil that you bought for the price agreed to in the futures contract.  Since the contract is for a higher price than you bought for, after subtracting your carrying costs hopefully you have made a profit.  These carrying costs can be why the futures price doesn't quite meet the spot price.

Comment: Thanks! So practically I am selling a contract for oil and at the same time  buying the same contract for oil ?

Comment: And benefit from the changes in price?

Comment: By the way my textbook always explained that being in a short position meant selling the contact and a long position meant buying the contract...

Comment: @GGGG no, you're only selling the contract and at the same time buying the actual oil in order to fulfill the requirements of the contract.  you benefit by the current difference in price, minus whatever costs you have to hold the oil (or whatever) until you deliver it.  it's arbitrage because one you execute the trade you have basically locked in this profit.

Comment: So even if I am in possession of short contract for oil , it still might imply that I don’t actually own the oil ?

Comment: @GGGG Yes, your textbook is correct.  You are selling the contract, which means you are agreeing to sell the underlying (oil or whatever) at the conclusion of the contract.

Comment: @GGGG Your being on the short side of the contract for oil implies that you are obligated to deliver the oil at the conclusion (i.e. since you don't buy out the contract before it closes like someone without intent to deliver would).  You actually do own the oil for a short period of time, but yes, in a sense your obligation and your ownership essentially cancel out.

Comment: Im sorry i didn't understand these last three phrases. So i understood that i am obligated to deliver the oil, but what does it mean that i don't buy out the contract before it closes like someone without intent to deliver would? Why does my obbligation cancel out and when do i own the oil? This is kind of confusing im sorry... because if i have to deliver the oil at the end on the contract, isn't that supposed to mean that i should already have the oil?

Comment: See if this clears some of this up: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cash-and-carry-arbitrage.asp

Comment: On the article it states : The trader would then hold or carry the asset until the expiration date of the futures contract and deliver the asset against the contract.  i don't get why i shouldnt be carrying the oil .. pleaase explain :(

Comment: @GGGG If you do this kind of arbitrage you DO carry the oil...

Comment: ok. so what is the point of buying other oil (buy the asset) if i am currently carrying the oil in my shorting position in the future contract which i have to sell?

Comment: So all of a sudden my oil disappears and i am not able to deliver it so i have to buy the asset again ? the thing that i dont understand is why i need to buy the oil again .

Comment: Why would i be buying the actual oil if i already have a selling contract and why is it so that in my short contract my 'obligation and ownership cancel out' as you said. Im sorry i know im being painfull but i greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @GGGG Being short the contract means you are obligated to sell.  But you don't have any to sell.  So you go and buy it on the spot market.  Now you have it to sell.

Comment: Ok. so you are confirming me that in my short position contract i do not own the oil .What is the point of having a contract with a linked commodity that you are going to sell if you dont have the ownership of the commodity? So you're practically saying that i have a contract to sell, but i actually dont have the ownership of the commodity even if i have a selling contract, so in order for this contract to be effectively sold i need to purchase the commodity.

Comment: last question: in a short position future contract when do i actually have the ownership of the commodity?

Comment: @GGGG the point is that you "simultaneously" buy the item that you are selling the contract to sell for.  It's like being at an apple market and seeing apples are selling for 50 cents, but that people are willing to pay 60 cents tomorrow for an apple.  You sell a contract to sell the apple tomorrow for 60 cents at the same time that you are buying the apple for 50 cents.  The whole purpose of the transaction is that there is a price discrepancy that you can profit from. You buy low and sell high (technically *agree* to sell high) at the same time.

Comment: @GGGG A short by itself never gives you ownership of anything as it creates an obligation to provide something.

Comment: "Selling" and "buying" a contract is not good terminology. Its better to think about "entering into a contract". Shorting oil is "entering into a contract to provide oil at a future point".